# ColdFusion XML parsing issue

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm still a bit of an xml idiot. Sometimes I get it and sometimes not.
I have the following XML which derives ultimately from a parsed .NET webservice output. I've wrapped it in a cfxml tag for the purposes of this question, but in reality I'm parsing an xml document.

```
<cfxml variable="local.vXML">
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
       <NewDataSet xmlns="">
              <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <ResponseCode>3</ResponseCode>
                     <ResponseText>Incorrect PIN. Please try again</ResponseText>
              </Table>
       </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram> 
</cfxml>
```

I want to get at the `<ResponseCode>` and `<ResponseText>` nodes.

How would I do that?

Various efforts, such as the following

```
<cfset Local.xSet = xmlSearch(local.vXML,"NewDataSet") />
<cfset Local.xSet = xmlSearch(local.vXML,"Table") />
<cfset Local.xSet = xmlSearch(local.vXML,"ResponseCode") />
```

yield an empty array

### THE SOLUTION

Thanks for Jake for his CF9 solution. Adapted below for CF8.

```
<cfset vResponseCodeXML = XMLSearch(Local.vXML, '//Table[@diffgr:id="Table1"]/ResponseCode')>
<cfset vResponseTextXML = XMLSearch(Local.vXML, '//Table[@diffgr:id="Table1"]/ResponseText')>
<cfset vResponseCode = vResponseCodeXML[1].XmlText>
<cfset vResponseText = vResponseTextXML[1].XmlText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<cfset respCode = XMLSearch(vXML, '//Table[@diffgr:id="Table1"]/ResponseCode')[1].XmlText>
<cfset respText = XMLSearch(vXML, '//Table[@diffgr:id="Table1"]/ResponseText')[1].XmlText>
```

Comment: I should note that this probably only works with CF9, due to my referencing the array element directly from the result of the function call.  I think earlier versions of CF might choke on that - if that gives you trouble, I can rework it.

Comment: Yep, spot on. CF8 had issues with the square array index bracket. I reworked it as per the edit in the original post.